# How to benchmark two Windows PC's performance

Tags: windows, performance, benchmarking

My old work laptop is a HP ProBook 640 G2 running Windows 7 Enterprise and has a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2401 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s) with 8.00 GB of RAM.

My new work laptop is a HP EliteBook 830 G5 running Windows 10 Enterprise and has a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz, 1896 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s) with 8.00 GB of RAM.

Common tasks on the old laptop take several seconds but take several minutes on the new laptop.

I work for a large company and potentially they have added their own bloat software to the new laptop.  I also see various Virtualization-based security properties as well as Secure Boot State and Device Encryption Support under system information on the new laptop which are not listed on the old laptop, and do not know whether this may be contributing to the lack of performance.

I wish to quantifiably compare the performance of the two laptops so I may voice my concern to my employer.  Ideally, it would be using some Microsoft sanctioned approach, however, am open to other approaches as well.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: One common benchmark test is Passmark: https://www.passmark.com/products/performancetest/download.php

Comment: @John Old laptop got 2138.0 (47th percentile) and new got 1844.4 (40th percentile).  2D graphics was 53rd percentile versus 11th percentile which was the biggest difference.  Also new performed less on memory mark.  Big difference in my actual tasks I do is bluebeam which might be caused by the bad 2d graphics.  Thanks

Comment: It also could be that the newer machine has a slower speed.  What makes you think 2nd graphics is bad

Comment: @John Old laptop had as 2d graphics score of 592 (53rd) and new had 290.8 (11th).  Bluebeam is a PDF software which I thought might rely strongly on 2d graphics.

Comment: Overall the new computer is not as fast as the old computer and your performance scores verify that.

Comment: @John.  Agree, but one wouldn't expect 60 times worse for some tasks.  Also, the CPU comparisons say it is faster.  Guess CPU is just one part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common benchmark test is Passmark:

passmark.com/products/performancetest/download.php

Passmark seems to be working well for you.

Answer (score 1):

For the CPU benchmark you can use prime95 if you are sure that both systems are stable.
Otherwice you can use CPU-Z for that.

For the GPU we have 3DMark, not yet known to crash or freeze windows by me personally.

For the HDD we have CrystalDiskMark, again a stable piece of software.

And i suppose there is nothing else to impact the performance on a laptop.